# Exporting plot as vector graphics in Octave or matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, vector-graphics

I know I can export a plot in octave as a PNG but is it possible to export a plot as a vector graphic image?

The reason I ask is that some of the points on my plot are very close together and I would like to be able to zoom in on them using another image program like inkscape or gimp.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just end your filename with `svg` instead of `png` and octave, at least, will do the right thing.

Comment: remark: matlab will too

Comment: Not used matlab in years, and just wanted to be explicit, but thanks for your comment, @thang